# How to Integrate Snapdeal affiliate api in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I want to integrate Snapdeal affiliate api in my application but not getting any refrence link to integrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of orders done by affiliate id using getConversions method.
Snapdeal uses third party (HasOffers) affiliate program. So you can get request and response parameter from this link.
http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/affiliate/controller/Affiliate_Report/method/getConversions

And then you can integrate as per your requirement.